# How to edit the Values of an Enum that are a Library

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, dll, enums

I'm trying to make a library in C# for creating roleplaying games (RPGs from here on out) in the console with graphics generated by a few classes I'm coding. I'd like to make it so that when using the library, one creates a number of rooms, as with typical RPGs. I have a public enum I've entitled `Rooms` for this purpose. The issue is that `Rooms` won't be editable by the user, as it will be part of the library and not their `Program.cs`, which should be all they need to make their RPG function with proper graphics (which requires `Rooms` to have certain values). However, they'll need to choose what rooms they want in their game, so this doesn't work.

How can I get around this? I was hoping that perhaps one could generate the values of an enum using either an XML file (perhaps you would run a program once to take the values in the XML file and plop them into the `Rooms` enum, and *then* begin coding your RPG), a dictionary, or an array, but I'm not sure it's possible.

How can I go about doing this in a way that will be convenient for the maker of the RPG (to reiterate, the objective is to make it possible for the coder to edit only the `Program.cs` file)? And would it make more sense to offer this RPG kit as a Visual Studio solution so that the coder can just edit everything him/herself?

Comment: Please clarify. By `Rooms`, do you mean a type of room? Like hallway, treasure room, etc? If your code relies on those different room types, have all of them available and let the person using your library use only the ones they need.

Comment: @RogueCSDev Sorry for the lack of clarity. By `Rooms`, I mean the rooms the coder wants to add to the game. Those can fall under the categories you mentioned, such as hallways and treasure rooms, but these are the more specific names of the rooms themselves. For example, if the coder were to edit the enum, you might see the following: HallOfTheGreatWizard, StinkyCheeseLair, etc.

Come to think about it, though, creating different types of rooms, perhaps a `RoomType` enum, could be helpful in the long run. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is [a question-and-answer resource, not a discussion forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers. You might try [programmers.se], which is for discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Comment: @AdiInbar Thanks! Is there any way to move it over to Programmers (I just signed up with my StackExchange account), or should I repost my question there?

Comment: @AdiInbar Programmers is not for discussions. It's for Software Development & Design Q&A. Do not crosspost. This could probably work for Programmers if we hone it down a bit but Game Development is likely a better host.

Comment: @WorldEngineer A bit confused by this back and forth. Which forum, Programmers or Game Development, should I have posted it to? Is there any way to move it over to one of those? And what is the difference between those? Ali Inbar makes a good point: it's more of an abstract question. Not sure which forum that means it would go to.

Comment: This is one of those borderline questions, on the one side it is about program design (which is [Programmers](http://programmers.stackechanges.com)) but on the other side it is about [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). My suggestion would be Game Dev and that you are explaining more an interface of IRoom than an enumerator, which the developer can then add/change as desired

Comment: @BerndLinde An interface is a clever solution. I haven't worked with them much before. I'll read up on them, give it a shot, and write whether or not it worked when I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: One question per question, please. Please ask a new question. I rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that `Rooms` should not be an `enum`. It should be an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Room {
    public abstract string RoomType {get;}
}
```

Developers using your library would create their own derived classes of `Room`:

```
public class ClassRoom : Room {
    public override string RoomType {get {return "ClassRoom";}}
}
```

Your library could then use reflection to find all the derived types of `Room` for display or other purposes.

Comment: I haven't used abstract classes before, but I just researched it. That could work. I'll give it a shot. I'm a tad confused on something, though. The way I'd like `Rooms` to function is as a way to concretely state the list of rooms, so that developers don't make mistakes when entering which room to render, etc., as they might with a string. I'm unsure of how that would be applied in this way. Perhaps my lack of knowledge on abstract classes is getting in the way; I apologize if that's the case here.

Comment: In other words, you don't know what I meant when I said "reflection". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx. You'll want to loop through all types (maybe all types in your user's assembly) and check to see if they are derived from `Room`.